# Change keyboard layout (Dvorak, Qwerty, etc.) in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, dvorak

How does one change the keyboard layout from [Qwerty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY) to another layout such as [Dvorak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard)?

I looked in:

- Settings > Region & Language
- Settings > Keyboard
- Help > Ubuntu Desktop Guide > Search

But I found no clue about how to change keyboard layout.

I tried searching for `English` in the `Region & Language` settings. But no `Dvorak` option appears, nor any other Qwerty or other layout — contrary to [this posting](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-add-and-switch-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux).

[image]

Comment: There are sub menus. Select for instance *English (United States)* and you'll find quite a few variants.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks that did it. I made an Answer from your suggestion.

Answer (score 15):

You were part way there.

Click one of those `English` items as shown in your screenshot, such as `English (United States)`. Clicking reveals an additional list of more options. In that secondary list you should see a `English (Dvorak)` item. Select, then click `Add` button.

You will now find a `en` menu on your main screen. Use that menu to choose between keyboard layouts (Dvorak, Qwerty).

[image: Screenshot of Settings > Region & Language]

Answer (score 0):

The Dvorak layout I'm getting on 20.10 is completely wrong in terms of the number keys as far as I can tell.  How do I get one with the right layout.