# Add several layouts to one keyboard language like in Windows

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I was only able to find a topic like this [Input language and keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609339/input-language-and-keyboard-layout) but maybe something changed since then.

In Windows, I can have, say, two languages, e.g., English and Spanish. For each language I can add multiple layouts, like `US keyboard`, `US international keyboard`, and so on. So I can switch between languages (for example, shift + alt) and between the layouts within one language (e.g., ctrl + shift).

Is there anything similar I can do in Ubuntu? Unfortunately, all I could do is to add different layouts as "languages" but this is incovenient.

Maybe it is possible to assign a specific keyboard shortcut to switch to a specific layout right away, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157633/change-keyboard-layout-dvorak-qwerty-etc-in-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts) help?

Comment: So you want a less intuitive way to do the same thing? Perhaps better to ditch the "Windows mentality" once and for all.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, unsure what you mean here but there are indeed something I find very convenient in Windows and I would like to have at least a similar thing in Ubuntu, that's it.

Comment: The reason for adding keyboards to languages in Windows is to enable the required variants for each language (e.g. "dead keys"). In Ubuntu you only add keyboard layouts and variants when needed, irrespective of the language or languages. You can toggle by selecting in the icon or with one single keyboard shortcut: Super + Space. That's why it's much simpler at the end of the day, you just have to know which variant or variants you need and can use any regardless of having the support for a certain language installed/enabled or not. Example: (...)

Comment: (...) Let's suppose you want to write in English and Spanish and you have a US International keyboard. So you add the standard and the "with dead keys" variants and you can use any anywhere anytime. In Windows you'd been adding "US International" to two different language supporting packs so when you choose ES it selects the "with dead keys" variant. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 21.10 go to settings and choose keyboard.
There you will have the option to change between keyboard layouts
You can also change the keyboard layouts on the fly pressing Windows(aka. super key) and space

Comment: The OP knows that already ;)